# Ruby - What is this output

Tags: ruby, proc-object

I know that this code may be not quite correct:

```
def print_string(&str)
puts str
end

print_string{"Abder-Rahman"}
```

But, when I run it, this is what I get:

```
#<Proc:0x03e25d98@r.rb:5>
```

What is this output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's the default string representation of a Proc object. Because "Abder-Rahman" is in braces, Ruby thinks you're defining a block.  Did you mean to put `str.call` inside of your function definition? That should call your block and return the string expression you defined inside it.

Comment: this would throw an exception, as the method is defined to expect a block, no normal arguments.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you've declared that the "`print_string`" method takes a block argument (confusingly named "`str`") and you simply print the proc itself.  You'd probably like to call the given procedure to see the string value it returns:

```
def call_proc(&proc)
  proc.call
end
call_proc { 'Foobar' }
# => "Foobar"
```

What you've discovered is the syntax sugar that if you decorate the last argument of a method definition with an ampersand `&` then it will be bound to the block argument to the method call.  An alternative way of accomplishing the same task is as follows:

```
def call_proc2
  yield if block_given?
end
call_proc2 { 'Example' }
# => 'Example'
```

Note also that procedures can be handled directly as objects by using [`Proc` objects](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Proc.html) (or the "lambda" alias for the Proc constructor):

```
p1 = Proc.new { 'Foo' }
p1.call # => "Foo"
p2 = lambda { 'Bar' }
p2.call # => "Bar"
```

Answer (score 2):

You're passing a block to the method, as denoted by the & prefix and how you're calling it.  That block is then converted into a Proc internally.

`puts str.call` inside your method would print the string, although why you'd want to define the method this way is another matter.

See Proc:
http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Proc.html

Answer (score 0):

When the last argument of function/method is preceded by the `&` character, ruby expect a `proc` object. So that's why `puts`'s output is what it is.

[This blog has an article about the unary & operator.](http://weblog.raganwald.com/2008/06/what-does-do-when-used-as-unary.html)